# Convert an array of objects to string

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, .net-4.5

I have `Person[] people` how could I transform this array into a string containing the CSV of each `Person`'s `Name`?

```
John, Donald, Jessika, ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string.Join(", ", people.Select(p => p.Name));
```

Comment: [As long as none of the names have a comma in them...](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: thanks for not commenting but just asking correctly and shortly the question ;)

Comment: @Rawling insightful, I'll keep that in mind. thanks.

Comment: @Serge no probs, all good :).

Comment: @Rawling, do you often  see comas in the people Names? )

Comment: @Serge I know one guy with semicolon. https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @AccessDenied, lool, still not a comma ;)

Comment: Martin Luther King, Jr.?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use linq for this:

```
people
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .Cast<string> //if needed
    .Aggregate((current, next) => $"{current}, {next}");
```

Comment: I don't see why do you need to cast a Name in string... Is there a need?

Comment: @Serge If the name is already a string then of course not :)

Comment: usually a Name is a string ;) thanks

Comment: also, I note the "$" feature of string does not fit the .net 4.5 version ;)

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest way is:**

```
string.Join(", ", people.Select(p => p.Name));
```

But if you do not understand the above approach you can always use  loops

```
StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
foreach (String person in people)
{
     csv.Append(person + ",");
}
```